# liquid template if statement issue

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, liquid, microsoft-dynamics, adxstudio-portals

Currently Im working in Dynamics 365 portals,
And my objective is to set entity form name dynamically on some condition.
but the problem is it always renders Form A even though the condition verifies.
Here is the code:

```
{%if user.age > 18%}
<div class="container">{% entityform name:'Form A' %}</div>
{%else%}
<div class="container">{% entityform name:'Form B' %}</div>
{%endif%}
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

Is the `user.age` field a custom field? In which case it will probably have a prefix, e.g. `user.xyz_age`.

This might not actually be a valid syntax `{%if user.age > 18%}`, shouldn't there be a few spaces in there? E.g. `{% if user.age > 18 %}`

Try printing `{{ user.age }}` to confirm the value is what you actually think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the attribute `age` is coming from an object created as a result of Fetchxml you have on this template.

My suggestion is to print along the the value samwhere, use `{{ user.age }}` and see if it is always grater than 18